# How to make categories pages wise different headers and footer in magento 2.3.1?

Tags: header, footer, magento2.3.1

*Want to make categories pages wise different header and footer in magento 2.3.1*

*example like have 4 categories so  want make 4 different header and footer that make maintain end of them.*

Answer (score 0):

> You can create different themes and apply as design updates category
>   wise, or you can update layout category wise in the design section of
>   category.

[image]

Comment: but this not maintain header and footer last process of page

Comment: for that new theme you can create a layout with different header and footer. Even you can create different page layout, in which you can set different headers and footers.